# SQL Update using value from join table

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I tried using this sql to update a new column in a table from a value in table that already exists.

```
 update "PROMOTION" t1  
      set "OFFER_CHAIN_ID" = poc."OFFER_CHAIN_ID"
 from "PROMOTION_OFFER_CHAIN" poc 
     inner join "PROMOTION" on "PROMOTION"."ID" = poc."PROMOTION_ID"
```

What happened is that the first value of the join got replicated in all the subsequent entries. about a both tables. The original table has unique values all the values in the updated column are the same.

Eventually I used this SQL instead.

```
update "PROMOTION" t1
    set "OFFER_CHAIN_ID" = poc."OFFER_CHAIN_ID"
from "PROMOTION_OFFER_CHAIN" poc
where 
    t1."ID" = poc."PROMOTION_ID"
```

This update works and duplicates all the data, 1000 unique elements in the original table, 1000 unique elements in the updated table.

Is this a bug, or is this the expected result?

Comment: Before doing this sort of update, it is often wise to run a similar select query first to see what the results are likely to be.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is behaving correctly.  Your original query is:

```
 update "PROMOTION" t1 
 --------^ 
      set "OFFER_CHAIN_ID" = poc."OFFER_CHAIN_ID"
      from "PROMOTION_OFFER_CHAIN" poc inner join
           "PROMOTION"
 -----------^
           on "PROMOTION"."ID" = poc."PROMOTION_ID"
```

Note that the table `PROMOTION` is mentioned twice.  Not good.  So, the `join` takes place, producing lots of rows.  Then there is no correlation to the `t1` version of the table.

You don't mention the database you are using.  In SQL Server, you would just do:

```
 update p  
      set "OFFER_CHAIN_ID" = poc."OFFER_CHAIN_ID"
      from "PROMOTION_OFFER_CHAIN" poc inner join
           "PROMOTION" p
           on p."ID" = poc."PROMOTION_ID";
```

Note the *alias* is used after the `update` (or table name with if there is no alias).  Now the table is mentioned only once, so the `update` should behave as desired.

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you suggested, and it didn't work. 
The error I got was:
 ERROR: relation "p" does not exist. 
 LINE 1: update p.